# Utilizando a função lm, do R, para resolver o problema autocorrelação

Tags: r, lm

Estou trabalhando com a função.

**lm(y~x)**

regressão simples, devido a testes verifiquei autocorrelação, logo a blibliográfia indica uma transformação.Algo parecido com:

**Y=B1*(1-p)+B2(X-(p*X[-1]))**

Que seria a aplicação da correção P no modelo, sendo que P é conhecido por mim.
Alguém conhece uma técnica de correção de autocorrelação, próximo a função apresentada?

Obrigado

Comment: Se existe autocorrelação nos dados, porque não utilizar o [modelo ARMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model)?

Comment: Marcus, é uma seria multivariada e não sei como programar para mais de uma variável explicativa. más é bem possivel ser resolvido com um processo ARIMA 2,1,2

Comment: Então usa um VARIMA (Vector ARIMA). Sugiro não tentar reinventar a roda.

Comment: Como programaria isso no R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se isso for uma serie temporal, o melhor é trabalhar com https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html, mas se você realmente quiser fazer isso, então:
crie uma coluna de atrasos (lag) e do valor p
lag<-x
lag<-c(NA,test)
P<-rep.int(p, length(test))

exemplo:

```
> te<-1:10
> te
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> te<-c(NA,te)
> te
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
>p<-rep.int(0.3, length(te))
```

E fazer fazer a lm para estimar B1 e B2:

```
lm(y~(1-P)+(X-(P*te))
```

Só cuidado, pois todas as colunas deverão ter o mesmo tamanho.